# Re-evaluating fields in a record after awk field separator change

Tags: macos, awk

(This is my first post here, so please forgive me if I am asking the question the wrong way.)

I am learning `awk` on my OSX Maverick. I am going through [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) on awk.

I am trying to reproduce something similar to the awk_example4a.awk in that tutorial.

So I came up with this awk program/script/arguments (not sure what you call it??):

```
BEGIN { i=1 }
{
    print "Line " i;
    print "$1 is " $1,"\n$2 is " $2, "\n$3 is " $3;
    FS=":";
    $0=$0;
    print "With the new FS - line " i;
    print "$1 is " $1,"\n$2 is " $2, "\n$3 is " $3;
    FS=" ";
    i++;
}
```

And the input file looks like this:

```
A1 B1:B2 C2
A1:A2 B2:B3 C3
```

What I am trying to do is to process each line/record first with the default `FS` (whitespace), and then re-process the same with a new `FS` (":"), then restore the default `FS` before going to the next record.

According to the tutorial, `$0=$0` is supposed to get `awk` to re-evaluate the fields using the new field separator, and thus supposedly giving me an output that looks like this:

```
Line 1
$1 is A1 
$2 is B1:B2 
$3 is C2
With the new FS - line 1
$1 is A1 B1
$2 is B2 C2
$3 is
Line 2
$1 is A1:A2 
$2 is B2:B3 
$3 is C3
With the new FS - line 2
$1 is A1
$2 is A2 B2
$3 is B3 C3
```

But instead, I get:

```
Line 1
$1 is A1 
$2 is B1:B2 
$3 is C2
With the new FS - the line 1
$1 is A1 
$2 is B1:B2 
$3 is C2
Line 2
$1 is A1:A2 
$2 is B2:B3 
$3 is C3
With the new FS - the line 2
$1 is A1:A2 
$2 is B2:B3 
$3 is C3
```

i.e. the fields have not been re-evaluated after the `FS` was changed.

So if `$0=$0` doesn't work (and nor do things like `$1=$1; $2=$2`), how do I get awk to re-evaluate the same line using a different `FS`?

Thank you.

Comment: Working to me if instead I print `print "With the new FS - line " i;
print "$1 is", $1` and so far. Investigating why.

Comment: Works for me with exactly the same script you posted ?

Comment: How do you launch it ? What is the shebang in your file ? `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` or something else ?

Comment: My exact command line was: `cat input.txt | awk -f test.awk`. And `test.awk` has an additional `#!/bin/awk -f` at the start of the file. EDIT: I changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` and the results were unchanged.

Comment: I just tried making test.awk executable, and ran `./test.awk input.txt`. The results still have not changed (i.e. `$0=$0` did not re-evaluate the fields as expected.) Really don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try using a different `awk`.

Comment: That's one method - using a different `awk`, but I am trying to learn and write scripts using only the default programs that comes with OSX Mavericks. If it can't be done, that's fine. I just wondered if there was a solution to this, without installing additional software. Thanks.

Comment: A workaround would be to assign each element of $0 to an array and process and print from there. I've also recently had issues with trying to be slick with `FS` like this. As far as Mac OSX goes, I'd recommend installing Homebrew, so that you can seamlessly install GAWK (i.e. GNU AWK), which might be more flexible with this kind of thing, and afaik is the standard AWK implementation on most Linux systems anyway. The AWK that comes with Mavericks is (I think) some variant of BSD's AWK, which lacks some nice features of GAWK anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl; dr:

**FreeBSD/OS X `awk` doesn't apply changes to `FS` (the field separator) until *after* the current record has finished processing** - this behavior is actually *POSIX-mandated* (see below).

**Workaround**: **Do not change `FS` and use function `split()` instead:**

```
{
    print "Line " ++i
    print "$1 is " $1 "\n$2 is " $2 "\n$3 is " $3
    split($0, flds, ":")   # split current line by ':' into array `flds`
    print "With the new FS - line " i
    print "field1 is " flds[1] "\nfield2 is " flds[2] "\nfield3 is " flds[3]
}
```

- Note how the `BEGIN` block was eliminated by relying on uninitialized variables defaulting to `0` in numeric contexts.
- The `,` instances were removed from the `print` statements, because each would insert a space (the default value of the output-field separator, `OFS`), which is not needed in this case.
- Given that the statements are newline-separated, `;` is not needed to terminate them.

Read on for the fun multi-platform compatibility details.

---

The [POSIX spec. for `awk`](http://man.cx/awk) states (emphasis mine):

```
Before the first reference to a field in the record is evaluated, the record shall be 
split into fields, according to the rules in Regular Expressions, 
**using the value of FS that was current at the time the record was read**.
```

With respect to assigning a new value to `$0` or a specific field, the same source states:

```
The symbol $0 shall refer to the entire record; setting any other field causes 
the re-evaluation of $0. Assigning to $0 shall reset the values of all other
fields and the NF built-in variable.
```

In other words: Given that the re-assignment case doesn't state otherwise, the only reference to the scope of a given `FS` value in the POSIX spec. mandates that it be *constant for a given input record*.
<sup>There is definitely ambiguity, and it would certainly help if the spec. resolved that - that said, the conservative and thus safer interpretation is to assume a *constant-while-processing-a-given-record* `FS`.</sup>

As such, it is FreeBSD/OS X `awk` that is the model citizen, whereas **GNU `awk` and also `mawk` offer more flexibility by NOT playing by the rules and applying `FS` changes even to the *current* record on re-assigning to `$0` or any specific field**.

Note, however, that GNU `awk` (as of v4.1.1) doesn't even change that behavior with the `--posix` option, whose express intent is to result in POSIX-compliant behavior.
If I'm reading the POSIX spec. correctly (do tell me whether I am), this should be considered a *bug*.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the solution. The code worked beautifully for me. Secondly, thank you for tidying up the code (e.g. I never know if that trailing `;` is needed or not.) Thirdly, thank you for the background info re POSIX compliance. And lastly, that "tl;dr" was a nice touch. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @LD99: I'm glad to hear it; my pleasure. Cross-platform compatibility is tricky business - you'll find that many people here assume _GNU_ `awk` when answering `awk` questions, so it's helpful to know the differences. Mostly (this case being an exception), FreeBSD/OSX awk's functionality is a _subset_ of GNU awk's, so if you restrict yourself to FreeBSD/OSX awk's functionality, there's a good chance it'll work on both - and, given that FreeBSD/OSX awk stays close to the POSIX standard, also in other awk implementations. However, GNU awk adds many very useful features.

Answer (score 0):

This is silly.  I likely have the same version of awk on my mac and was able to reproduce this on Snow Leopard.

```
% awk -version
awk version 20070501
```

`FS` doesn't appear to be re-assignable while processing the same line in this version of awk using the `$0=$0` technique.  It is possible to re-assign `$0` by introducing `getline`.  It should be considered overkill - especially because it's issuing a command in a sub-process - but nothing else worked for me.

Here's an executable awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { i=1 }

{
    print "Line " i
    print "$1 is " $1 "\n$2 is " $2 "\n$3 is " $3
    FS=":"

    # here's the trick
    cmd = sprintf( "echo %s", $0 )
    cmd | getline
    close(cmd)

    print "With the new FS - line " i
    print "$1 is " $1 "\n$2 is " $2 "\n$3 is " $3
    FS=" " # this will work for the next line
    i++
}
```

The `cmd` is built using `sprintf()` because it's easier to get the `cmd` built correctly that way.  `cmd` is then run with the output piped to `getline` which re-assigns `$0` to the output of the command (an `echo` of the current line) recalculates the field separators.  Afterwards, the `cmd` is closed to prevent leaky pipes.

As others have suggested this will work in GNU awk which is easy to install in Mavericks, but painful on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and explanation. I tested it out and it worked perfectly - though I don't know anything about the `cmd` command and will have to look into it a bit deeper later on. Incidentally, I am using OSX Mavericks and I have the same version of `awk` (20070501). Thanks again!!

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! this is **dangerous** as any data passing through the echo command can contain shell commands and so the input to awk could get executed by the shell. Use `$(uname -a)` as input and you will see.