# awk: process input from pipe, insert result before pattern in output file

Tags: regex, awk, scripting

I am trying to process an input stream through a simple awk function, and insert the results before an anchor pattern in an existing file. My function works fine, but I can't convince awk to write the results where and how I want them. The input is being piped as XML from hunspell to my script, which accepts as an argument the output file.

```
hunspell -L -H ./text.xml | ./parse.awk ./output.xml

#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#

function buildObjs()
{
    a["x"]=$4*mils; a["y"]=-$5*mils; a["w"]=$6*mils; a["h"]=$7*mils
    print "## element" NR+1 " [x]="a["x"]" [y]="a["y"]" [width]="a["w"]" [height]="a["h"]
    print "set fsize("NR+1") {FALSE}"
    print "set fmargin("NR+1") {FALSE}"
    print "set fmaster("NR+1") {TRUE}"
    print "set ftype("NR+1") {box}"
    print "set fname("NR+1") {"a["w"],a["h"]"}"
    print "set fatt("NR+1") {1}"
    print "set dplObjectSetup("NR+1",TRA) {"a["x"],a["y"]"}"
    print "set fnum("NR+1") {}"
    return 0
}

BEGIN {
    FS = "[\" ]+"
    mils = "0.3527"
    for (i = 0; i < ARGC; i++) {
        # Use this block to identify the output file we need to write to.
        if (ARGV[i] ~ /output.+/) {
            outFile=ARGV[i]
            delete ARGV[i]
        }
    }
    while ((getline line < outFile) > 0) {
        if (line ~ !/set lineno \{.+\}/) {
            print line
        }
    }
    close(outFile)
}

{
    buildObjs()
}

END {
    print "set lineno {"NR+2"}"
    while ((getline line < outFile) > 0) {
        if (line ~ /set mode \{.+\}/) {
            print line
        } else
            print line
    }
    close(outFile)
}
```

The anchor pattern I'm looking for in the outFile is "set lineno {3}". In the stream from text.xml, there are 20 lines, and the buildObjs function loops on every line of input, meaning I'm defining 20 objects in the output file, iterating the object count with NR+1 as I go. The number of lines to be processed will vary from job to job. As a bonus question, the anchor pattern needs to be updated so that "set lineno {3}" becomes "set lineno {NR+2}" with whatever NR+2 resolves to for that job. Presumably I will do this in the END block, but right now I just need to get my new objects into the output file.

So in summary, stream input into my awk script, process it with my function, insert the result before a pattern in an existing file, update the anchor pattern and close the modified file. This is my first substantial use of awk outside of one-liners embedded in bash scripts. Any help is most appreciated.

**EDIT:** I've updated the code to reflect comments from Jonathan.

**EDIT2:** Updated the `END` block. This code now does what I want.

**EDIT3:** Here are a few lines being piped into my script:

```
<w box="45.2044 92.54 61.5253 9.503" xoffset="6.27627 12.6244 19.4125 25.5994 32.2113 38.159 48.5253">Technews</w>

<w box="407.31 91.6 107.774 10.443" xoffset="1.8024 6.7944 12.1711 18.8203 29.2284 36.5576 43.2034 50.0661 56.641 61.0251 68.0434 74.6553 85.0634 92.0651 97.1957 100.274">Issue256:June27th</w>

<w box="67.923 132.463 32.747 7.337" xoffset="6.259 14.168 19.129 21.747">DALIM</w>
```

An excerpt from the outFile:

```
#    file.encoding: UTF-8
# sun.jnu.encoding: UTF-8

set toolVersion {1.20}
set ftype(0) {pgs}
set fsize(0) {FALSE}
set fmargin(0) {FALSE}
set fsize(1) {TRUE}
set fmargin(1) {TRUE}
set fmaster(1) {FALSE}
set ftype(1) {pgs}
set fname(1) {}
set fatt(1) {0}
set dplObjectSetup(1,TRA) {}
set fnum(1) {}
>> New data inserted here.
set lineno {2} << This number updated to reflect the total number of objects.
set mode {1}
set preservePDF {1}
set preservePDFAction {Continue}
```

So, as I hope this clarifies, after processing the piped input, I'm inserting additional blocks starting with "set fsize()" and ending with "set fnum()", incrementing as I go, and summing the total number of blocks in "set lineno {}" before finally appending the trailing lines after "set lineno {}".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your executable awk script that produces the ordering you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="[{}]"; mils="0.3527"; built=1 }

FNR==NR {
    if( $1 !~ /set lineno/ ) {
        if( lineno != "" ) { footer[++cnt]=$0; if(cnt==3) { FS = "[\" ]+" } }
        else print
    }
    else { lineno=$2 }
    next
}

FNR!=NR && NF > 0 { built += buildObjs( built+1 ) }

END {
    print "set lineno {" built "}"
    for(i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) {
        print footer[i]
    }
}

function buildObjs( n )
{
    x=$4*mils; y=-$5*mils; w=$6*mils; h=$7*mils
    print "## element" n " [x]=" x " [y]=" y " [width]=" w " [height]=" h
    print "set fsize(" n ") {FALSE}"
    print "set fmargin(" n ") {FALSE}"
    print "set fmaster(" n ") {TRUE}"
    print "set ftype(" n ") {box}"
    print "set fname(" n ") {" w " " h "}"
    print "set fatt(" n ") {1}"
    print "set dplObjectSetup(" n ",TRA) {" x " " y "}"
    print "set fnum(" n ") {}"
    return 1
}
```

When put into a file called `awko` it would be run like:

```
hunspell -L -H ./text.xml | ./awko ./output.xml -
```

I don't have hunspell installed, so I tested this by running the Edit3 piped output from a file via cat:

```
cat ./pipeddata | ./awko ./output.xml -
```

*Notice the `-` at after the output file.*  It's telling `awk` to read from `stdin` as the 2nd input to the awk script, which lets me deal with the first file with the standard `FNR==NR { do stuff; next }` logic.

Here's the breakdown:

- For personal preferences, I moved the `buildObjs()` function to the end of the script.  Notice I added a `n` argument to it - `NR` won't be used in the output.  I dropped the `a` array because it didn't seem to be necessary and changed it's return from `0` to `1`.
- In the `BEGIN` block, setup `output.xml` file parsing, and `mils`
- Whenever the `FILENAME` changes to `-`, change `FS` for parsing that input.  The piped data `FS` could instead be set on the command line between the output file and the `-`.
- When `FNR==NR` handle the first file
- Basically, print the "header" info when your anchor hasn't been read
- When the anchor is read, store it's value in `lineno`
- After the anchor is read, store the last of the `output` file into the `footer` array in `cnt` order.  Knowing there are only 3 lines at the end, I "cheated" to adjust the `FS` before the first record is read from `STDIN`.
- When `FNR!=NR` and the line isn't blank (`NF>0`), process the piped input, incrementing `built` and passing it with a offset of `1` as an arg to buildObjs() ( as `built` starts with a value of 0 ).
- In the `END`, the `set lineno` line is reconstructed/printed with the sum of `lineno` and `built`.
- Then the footer from the first file is printed in order based on the `cnt` variable

Using the `cat` form, I get following:

```
#    file.encoding: UTF-8
# sun.jnu.encoding: UTF-8

set toolVersion {1.20}
set ftype(0) {pgs}
set fsize(0) {FALSE}
set fmargin(0) {FALSE}
set fsize(1) {TRUE}
set fmargin(1) {TRUE}
set fmaster(1) {FALSE}
set ftype(1) {pgs}
set fname(1) {}
set fatt(1) {0}
set dplObjectSetup(1,TRA) {}
set fnum(1) {}
## element2 [x]=32.6389 [y]=-21.7 [width]=3.35171 [height]=0
set fsize(2) {FALSE}
set fmargin(2) {FALSE}
set fmaster(2) {TRUE}
set ftype(2) {box}
set fname(2) {3.35171 0}
set fatt(2) {1}
set dplObjectSetup(2,TRA) {32.6389 -21.7}
set fnum(2) {}
## element3 [x]=32.3073 [y]=-38.0119 [width]=3.68325 [height]=0
set fsize(3) {FALSE}
set fmargin(3) {FALSE}
set fmaster(3) {TRUE}
set ftype(3) {box}
set fname(3) {3.68325 0}
set fatt(3) {1}
set dplObjectSetup(3,TRA) {32.3073 -38.0119}
set fnum(3) {}
## element4 [x]=46.7197 [y]=-11.5499 [width]=2.58776 [height]=0
set fsize(4) {FALSE}
set fmargin(4) {FALSE}
set fmaster(4) {TRUE}
set ftype(4) {box}
set fname(4) {2.58776 0}
set fatt(4) {1}
set dplObjectSetup(4,TRA) {46.7197 -11.5499}
set fnum(4) {}
set lineno {4}
set mode {1}
set preservePDF {1}
set preservePDFAction {Continue}
```

Seems like your `buildObj()` function logic needs some attention to get things just the way you want (I suspect the indexes you've chosen need shifting).

Comment: Thanks for your elegant solution, and clear explanation. I've learned a lot from this exercise. One comment and one question: you explicitly added a comma in the output, which is a syntax error for the format I'm using (each field is space-delimited `set code{x y}`). I see now this is not clear from my original question, but the inserted objects must start at "2" (`set fsize(2)`), as there is always one object to start with (`set fsize(1)`). That's why it looks like my indices are off (and why I used `NR+1`); how do I tweak your code so that we start at object 2 using a record 1 from stdin?

Comment: Glad to be of help.  I can make some edits in a bit. `built` can be set in the `BEGIN` block to start at 1 and the commas are easy to remove.  I think I misunderstood the purpose of the 2 in the `set lineno` line in the final output - it's really just `built`.  The indexes I thought were off in `buildObj()` were the `columns` (`$4,$5,$6,$7`) because height is always 0 for me (maybe start at `$3` instead?).  Also I see all 0s for the first record which seems wrong to me - may have something to do with the awk I'm using.

Comment: I tried starting with `built=1`, which fixes the object offset, but the first new block always has values of zero, as if it's reading a blank record; the rest of the blocks (`set fsize 3`and onwards) are all correct using your original code. I'm using gawk, and my columns all line up with the correct values. I just can't figure out why the the first block isn't populated with the values from the first record.

Comment: I think it's deciding not to re-evaluate `FS` for the first record "in-line".  I thought that might have been because of the posix awk I'm using, but appears to affect your gawk as well.  Try calling it this way instead:  `hunspell -L -H ./text.xml | ./awko ./output.xml FS=="[\\\" ]+" -` where the `FS` is being set explicitly before the `STDIN` arg of `-` with an extra escape (`\\ `) for the bash shell I'm using.  `FS` could instead be set when `cnt==3` in the footer array block to get the first `STDIN` record data to appear, but that feels a little like "cheating" to me :)

Comment: I've made edits for 'built' initialization, 'set lineno' and the `FS` value not getting set before `STDIN` using the "cheating" method (since that let me skip editing the run instructions).  I also updated the output I'm seeing.  I still think the height shouldn't =0 and that `buildObj()`'s fields should be `$3,$4,$5,$6` instead of `$4,$5,$6,$7`, but I left that alone.

Comment: I figured out what I was missing before for the `FS` switch in the original version.  It was missing a 'recompute' of the line using a `$0=$0` which works in gawk.  In posix awk, re-assignment of `$0` won't necessarily work while processing the same line, which is why assigning it before the line is read works ( via the command line or the "cheat" ).  See more on the subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24777653/1259917)

Comment: Excellent work. I think there may be an error in the sample data I supplied, as my selected indices work correctly. One minor revision: I had to add "+1" to `print "set lineno {" built+1 "}"`as the count in `lineno` must be one more than the total number of objects. Thanks again for your help and clear explanations. **Edit:** I just noticed the cause of the shifted indices. The streamed text has leading space on each line which is not reflected in the sample data. Given that were using space as a field delimiter, that's what's causing our results to differ by one.

Answer (score 0):

The main action `{ buildObjs(); PROFIT??; }` (for whatever `PROFIT??` means) is acted on for each line since there is no pattern before it.  You should add a pattern to recognize where you want the output added:

```
/set lineno \{3\}/ { buildObjs() }
                   { print }
```

The first recognizes the pattern (`{` is an `awk` regex metacharacter, so it must be escaped), and the second ensures that the line is printed after the output from `buildObjs()`.  Reverse the lines if you want the `set lineno {3}` to come first, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but that will only work if the pattern I'm searching for is in the **input** stream. I need to insert the processed lines into the **output** file just before the anchor pattern.

Comment: What I showed finds the line with the anchor pattern, prints what you need inserted before the anchor pattern, and then prints the anchor pattern line.  That's what you say you need, I believe.  (The complete `awk` script would include the function definition and the `BEGIN` block, just as now.  All this does is replace your current 'other code' with two lines, one to invoke the function in the correct place, and the other to print the data from the input to the output.)

Comment: Thanks to your help, I think I'm pretty close, and I've updated the code to reflect your input. Last thing, I need to preserve the trailing lines of the output file which occur after the anchor pattern. Would I do something similar in the `END` block as I did in `BEGIN`? And am I on the right track overall?

Comment: Your updated code still runs `buildObjs()` for every line, which was not what I thought you wanted, but then you are doing some contorted stuff with `getline` in your `BEGIN` block.  Gosh; I don't follow your logic.  If you want to suppress the `set lineno` output until you know how many records there are, that's perfectly doable without those contortions.  It looks like you're making it more complicated just for the fun of making it complex.

Comment: OK; I've misunderstood the requirements...but since the function prints stuff each time it is called, saying you want the results inserted before the `set lineno` line doesn't make much sense to me; the printing will appear when the function is called, so it will appear for each line. You'd have to have the function return a string which you'd accumulate, and you can then print the output when you please.  I recommend you show a minimal (2-5 line input), and the desired output from that, because I'm still confused about what you want.

Comment: Sorry if I have been obtuse. I'm certainly not trying to overcomplicate things. I do want to run `buildObs()`on every line of the input, with the results of the function inserted before `set lineno {.+}` in the outFile. I then want to modify `set lineno {.+}` with `NR+2`. Finally, I want to preserve the trailing lines of outFile. The latest code does that, though I'm wide open to simplifying it any way possible. Typically, awk documentation says readline is not for beginners, so I'm not surprised if I'm using it wrong.